# Converting Luxon DateTime ISO format to Java LocalDateTime

Tags: java, luxon

My frontend vue application sends a luxon DateTime object to a Spring Boot backend which has a LocalDateTime field, however, java is unable to parse the DateTime object. I have tried using both luxon's toSQL() and toISO() methods to format, but of no avail.

What would be the optimal way of sending date time from a vue application to a java backend?

example request:

```json
"date_deadline": "2024-03-07 14:54:51.440 +08:00"
```

The java entity looks as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "todos")
public class Todo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    private LocalDateTime date_created;
    @Column (name = "date_deadline")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private LocalDateTime date_deadline;
}
```

When passing the json in the request body, I get the following 400 response:

```json
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String \"2024-03-07 14:54:51.440 +08:00\": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2024-03-07 14:54:51.440 +08:00' could not be parsed at index 10",
```

Comment: *example request* That's `OffsetDateTime` not `LocalDateTime` though improperly formatted, so you'll need a formatter too

Comment: The value `2024-03-07 14:54:51.440 +08:00` has an offset from UTC, that means it won't be parseable by a `LocalDateTime`, which does not have or store an offset. Use an `OffsetDateTime` instead, but that alone will not suffice, you will have to provide the pattern, too: `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z` is likely to work.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is not the right type to use for the point in time something is created. Use `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` here. A `LocalDateTime`*cannot* define a point in time since by design it lacks time zone and offset from UTC. Also as others have said your string contains an offset, so `OffsetDateTime` would be the obvious type to convert to.

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

Parse your non-standard input as [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. Change your field declaration to match.

```java
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "2024-03-07 14:54:51.440 +08:00" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS xxx" ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2024-03-07T14:54:51.440+08:00

### No, not `LocalDateTime`

Your input includes three parts: date, time, and offset-from-UTC.

A `LocalDateTime`, in contrast, has only two parts: date and time, but lacks the offset.

| Type | Date | Time | Offset | Appropriate? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "2024-03-07 14:54:51.440 +08:00" | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |  |
| `OffsetDateTime` | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |  |
| `LocalDateTime` | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ |  |

### `OffsetDateTime`

Change the type of your field to `OffsetDateTime`.

```
private OffsetDateTime date_deadline;
```

### `Instant`

Alternatively, use `Instant` if you want to adjust values to an offset of zero. Generally best to use an offset of zero unless your business rules deem it important to remember the original offset.

### No, not ISO 8601

Your input string is *not* in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. In standard format, the middle SPACE should be a `T`, and the SPACE before the offset should be deleted. Example: `2024-03-07T14:54:51.440+08:00`.

Ideally, you would educate the publisher of your data to use strictly compliant ISO 8601 formats only when exchanging date-time values textually.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

The *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later use standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no formatting pattern need be defined.

For your non-standard inputs, we need to define a formatting pattern using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```java
String input = "2024-03-07 14:54:51.440 +08:00";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS xxx" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having this problem because the date format that Vue sends is not compatible with the format that LocalDateTime has in Java, which is ISO-8601 ("2024-03-07T14:54:51.440"). You can solve this in several ways:

1. **Change the date format in Vue:**

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

const luxonDateTime = DateTime.local(); // Replace this with your Luxon DateTime object
const isoDateTime = luxonDateTime.toISO(); // Format to ISO-8601 string
```

2. **Send the date as String**. You can convert the date in Vue to a String with the ISO-8601 format and send it to the backend.
3. **Custom Deserialization in Spring Boot.** You can modify the default deserializer to fit your format.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {
        String dateTimeString = jsonParser.getText();
        return LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
    }
}
```

You can use it with the annotation `@JsonDeserialize` in your entity.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@Entity
@Table(name = "todos")
public class Todo {
    // Other fields

    @Column(name = "date_deadline")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime dateDeadline;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by removing the offset:

```js
DateTime.now().toISO({ includeOffset: false })
```

2024-03-07T18:18:30.932

Comment: While it appears to work, it’s exactly the wrong "solution". You are throwing away crucial information to make things fit.

Comment: That's not unlike deleting the AM/PM from a 12-hour time because of some problem or other. In your case, it's more subtle so it will be harder to predict how and when it will bite you